# Limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin[x]}{[x]}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to find the limit  of  $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin[x]}{[x]}$$ where [.] represents the greatest integer function.
I tried to take up an infinitesimally small number $h$ and took up the  Right Hand Limit and Left Hand limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin[x]}{[x]}$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin[h]}{[h]}$$

I am stuck over here, though I know that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$ But here I see that since $h$ is a very small positive number$[h]$ itself becomes zero and we get
$$\Rightarrow  \frac{\sin 0}{0}.$$ Does this shows that the RHL doesn't exist or am I at fault somewhere?

Comment: What are RHL, LHL, and $[\cdot]$?

Comment: Right hand limit and left hand limit

Comment: I don't know how to prove it, but it seems to not exist. As seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x+to+0+sin(floor(x))%2F(floor(x))).

Comment: Quite right, the RHL does not exist, $0/0$ is not defined. But the LHL does. What can you conclude ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The domain of the function excludes $[0,1)$, so that

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\sin(-1).$$

Answer (score 5):

For $-1 \le x<0$, you have $[x]=-1$, so for $x$ in that interval:
$$\frac{\sin[x]}{[x]}=\frac{\sin(-1)}{-1}=\sin 1$$
Which makes the left-handed limit $\sin 1$.

For $0 \le x<1$, you have $[x]=0$ so $\tfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is not defined in neighborhoods on the right of $x=0$.

Comment: But sinx / x exists and equal to 1.

Comment: You probably mean the limit of that function (for x to $0$), but note that $[x] \ne x$...